# Is it possible to convert requirejs modules to commonjs?

Tags: requirejs, commonjs

It's [already possible to convert commonjs modules to requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html#autoconversion), but I still want to know whether it's possible to do the reverse. Is there any way to convert requireJS modules to commonJS, instead of vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Many sites including Sound Cloud have developed their own conversion tool.

Mozilla has developed a nice little module called SweetJS. Basically allows you to define macros in JavaScript. To use in Node.js, you'll need to use it's binary to actually use the macros, as it's not available through runtime.

http://sweetjs.org/

**EDIT:**

Yehuda, one of the developers of Ember.js [has released a transpiler module.](https://github.com/wycats/js_module_transpiler)

It is written in Ruby, and not JavaScript, but perhaps someone will convert it over. Nonetheless, you can use it within Node.js by forking a ruby process.

Comment: Is SoundCloud's conversion tool publicly available?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Not that I know of, though, a lot of people on their dev blog asked for it, so they may open source it. They used a different approach with the UglifyJS library to manipulate the AST.

Comment: Also, the page on SweetJS doesn't specifically mention requireJS. Is any further relevant information available?

Comment: @AndersonGreen That's right. It only mentions macros. You'll have to build your own macro for module system conversion. The class macro can get you started. I was building my module conversion macros, so I'll see if I still have them.

Comment: Good luck finding the macros - that sounds really useful. :)

Comment: @AndersonGreen Added a module that converts/transpiles module formats.

Comment: sweetjs is sweet for manipulation of js code, but its not specifically solving most module conversions challenges and incompatibilities - check  http://urequire.org and my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Manually, it should be possible.

A **require.js** module looks like:

```
define('module', ['dep1', 'dep2'], function(dep1, dep2) {
   return myFunction = function() {
   };

});
```

Exporting to a **CommonJs module** shouldn't be too hard:

```
var dep1 = require('dep1');
var dep2 = require('dep1');

exports.myFunction = function() {
};
```

You don't have to return a function, it can be an object too:

```
define('module', ['dep1', 'dep2'], function(dep1, dep2) {
   return {
     myFunction1: function() {
     },
     myFunction2: function() {
     }
   };

});
```

...

```
var dep1 = require('dep1');
var dep2 = require('dep1');

exports.myObject = {
     myFunction1: function() {
     },
     myFunction2: function() {
     }
};
```

**Edit:** [converting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14158029/1916258) is also possible.

Comment: There actually are conversion tools available - see the latest answer to this question.

Comment: What would the above require.js example look like with multiple functions? Would the other functions be declared inside the same callback as `function1`?

Comment: You can return multiple function if you use an object, as i added in the answer.

Comment: Also, how would the `define` function be called if the module didn't require any other modules? Would it be written as `define('module', function(){});`, or would it need to be written as `define('module', [], function(){});`?

Comment: define('module', function(){}); Or even shorter: define(function(){});

Comment: It might also be possible to simply create a commonjs wrapper for a requireJS module (using the node.js loader for requirejs). http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#3

Answer (score 6):

Yes its possible if you use [uRequire](http://github.com/anodynos/urequire), a tool I wrote  specifically for javascript module format conversion -  *AMD/Requirejs* --> *commonjs/nodejs* and back (plus more).

It seems as a trivial AST manipulation & dependencies resolution @ start, but  module formats are **incompatible** in many ways apart from syntax:

- **dependency/path resolution** : commonjs uses fileRelative (eg
  '../PersonModel') whereas AMD can also use package-relative (eg
  'Models/PersonModel')
- **execution environment**: commonJs modules are loaded synchronously, whereas AMD are loaded asynchronously (AMD also has the asynchronous `require` version `require(['dep1', dep2'], function(dep1, dep2){})` as its targeted mainly for the browser).

These are also other differences (eg AMD loader plugins) but in general writing against each one 'locks' you in that format. .

uRequire enables you to author in AMD or commonJS and convert to the other easily (or convert to UMD), hence enjoying modular Javascript without the boilerplate.

Comment: Nice work, however the concrete AMD-to-commonsjs transformation is not documented there. Could you please create an example, using urequire, about doing the AMD-to-commonsjs  since it's what's asked? Thanks!